# why the spark-assembly-1.3.0-hadoop1.0.4.jar can't work on the Oozie share lib?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, oozie

I am running Hadoop 1.1.2 and used Oozie 3.3.2 successfully to run Java MR jobs.
When I use Spark in the Oozie environment, I put the spark-assembly-1.3.0-hadoop1.0.4.jar in the shared libs. When I run the spark job, Oozie can’t start the job and reports:

> Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [haflow.component.test.test1],
>   main() threw exception,
>   org/spark-project/guava/util/concurrent/ThreadFactoryBuilder
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/spark-project/guava/util/concurrent/ThreadFactoryBuilder

In the “Task Logs: 'attempt_201506031653_0040_m_000000_0'”,the classpath contains the jar,as shown in the report:

> /opt/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/taskTracker/distcache/3086706763921881131_-2028818788_2910849/ip/user/root/share/lib/spark-assembly-1.3.0-hadoop1.0.4.jar

So,why can't Oozie find the Spark jar?

Additionally ‘spark-assembly-1.3.0-hadoop1.0.4.jar’ is also in HDFS at /user/root/share/lib.

But when I tried it on the command line, it worked successfully.

Can you tell me how to fix this?